# Entity Framework 6 Generic Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

Anyone knows how to add/attach many-to-many entities in a generic way?

Normally you would just need to add the entities to the parent entity collection set. like Class.Students.Add(student); I need a way to attach them in a generic way.

I was able to get the Set Types and Entity Instances.

```
Type entityType;
Type relatedEntityType;

object entityInstance;
object relatedEntityInstance;

?? db.Set(entityType).link(relatedEntityType);
?? db.Set(relatedEntityType).link(entityInstance);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to add them in a genric way? I don't understand the use case of your problem.

Comment: I only have the Entity set name ("Student"), Entity Key ("1") for 2 related entities and need to join the 2 records just using these data from my Audit trail table. It's like a revert/back function.